# How do i pivot this redshift table? (Revised question)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

- Note: This is a revised version of another question - i realized i didnt have complete requirements (sorry about that!)

I have a Redshift table called `metadata` with the following columns:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | code1 | my value |
| 1001 | code2 | another |
| 1001 | code3 | yet another |
| 1002 | code1 | new one |
| 1002 | code2 | here |
| 1002 | code3 | last |
| 1003 | code1 | hello |
| 1003 | code2 | goodbye |
| 1004 | code2 | now |
| 1004 | code3 | then |

I'd like to have a query that return it as:

| id | code1 | code2 | code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | my value | another | yet another |
| 1002 | new one | here | last |
| 1003 | hello | goodbye |  |
| 1004 |  | now | then |

Note that not all ID's will have all 3 codes. Some will have 1 or 2 of them, others all 3, and others still, none.

Comment: The answer to your first question works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
Select id,
       Max(case when key = 'code1' then value end) as code1,
       Max(case when key = 'code2' then value end) as code2,
       Max(case when key = 'code3' then value end) as code3
  From your_table t
 Group by id;
```